# Knockout, Why doesn't my function fire on the clickevent?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

HTML:

```
<div data-bind='click: registerClick'>
  <img src="image.png" width="450px" />
</div>
<div data-bind='visible: content'>
  content
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
this.content = ko.observable(false);

//Named function triggers at the start 
//(after pressing f5, and doesn't trigger when I click the image)
this.registerTClick = toggleContent(this.content);

//unamed function only triggers at the clickevent.
this.registerClick = function () {
if (this.content() == false) {
  this.content(true);
}};
```

I'd like to get the first one to behave like the second one.

Comment: what you mean first one to behave like second one?

Answer (score 2):

Writing `toggleContent(this.content)` immediately executes your `toggleContent` function and if it is not returning a `function` then it breaks the click binding.

So you need to set your `registerTClick` to a function reference or something which returns a function reference.

In your case you can use the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a new function from your `toggleContent` which receives the `this.content` when it gets called:

```
this.registerTClick = toggleContent.bind(this, this.content);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Hae8/).